# Sony SDK support for the DSCRX100 -2

Tags: sony-camera-api

Just downloaded the Camera Remote API beta SDK from Sony website. No mention of the DSCRX100-2
Can any one tell me if the  DSCRX100-2 is compatible or even partly compatible with any of the other models listed in the SDK documents.

It appears that this model has basic control from the PlayMemories app. So I kind of assume that the API released has also some compatability. Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation from Sony re this camera and the relevant compatibility.

Comment: Since the sdk is still in beta then you probably are not going to find many people on here who have made use it, especially if the api is not yet fully documented or lacking content.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the functionality of a Sony SDK.

Comment: Chris I'm a newbie here, I followed post as per Sony developers website. Can you suggest where to post?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if the camera does not appear in the Camera API compatibility list then it will not work with the API.

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/